# В VS code python не дает ввести данные в консоли

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input

[image: программа на python в vs code]

В vs code запускаю задачу квадратное уравнение и не могу ввести исходные данные. Где собака зарыта? Как исправить?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Вывод во вкладку "Выходные данные" идет из-за запуска кода через расширение [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). Ввод через эту вкладку не возможен.

Нужно удалить (или временно отключить) расширение code runner, и использовать для запуска кода просто обычное расширение для python ([ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)). Тогда ввод/вывод будет работать через вкладку терминала, а не через выходные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте терминал а не вкладку "Выходные данные". Или попробуйта запустить скрипт через консоль cmd.